# Multithreading with a While Loop

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

So below is my code where Buyers and Sellers interact with Cars and a Car Showroom. It runs as it should, as far as I know. However, Threads only run after day 20+ in the While Loop in Main. Could anyone help point out why this is?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CarShowroom carShowroom = new CarShowroom();
    Random rand = new Random();

    int day = 1;

    while (day <= 30){
       System.out.println("Day " + day + " beginning. There are " + carShowroom.getCars().size()  + " cars in the showroom today.");

        int randomSeller = rand.nextInt(3);
        int randomBuyer = rand.nextInt(3);

        for (int j = 0; j <= randomSeller; j++){
            Seller seller = new Seller(carShowroom);
            Thread mySellerThread = new Thread(seller);
            mySellerThread.start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= randomBuyer; i++){
            Buyer buyer = new Buyer(carShowroom);
            Thread myBuyerThread = new Thread(buyer);
            myBuyerThread.start();
        }

        day++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to explain how you know that "Threads only run after day 20+", but basically threads take some time to start, so your loop will execute many times between calling `Thread.start()` and the thread starting to execute.

Comment: Please show example output to help us understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps your loop is executing quicker than Thread.start() will start.

Answer (score 0):

It is either caused by the fact that spawned threads are not immediately ready to execute code or simply you might have single core machine and main thread occupies cpu then the other threads have to wait until cpu time slice assigned to the main thread ends. In order to achieve tiny bit of determinism within yours program execution, you could put `Thread.sleep(100)` in the main loop to create an opportunity for the other threads to run. That should alter the order of execution.

Comment: You should never use `Thread.sleep` to "achieve tiny bit of determinism within yours program execution"

Comment: Of course I disagree, as we can see author is still learning the basics. He might not be aware of any mechanism that will allow him to introduce execution determinism. So in order to focus at the problem which is thread scheduling, for sure he can give it a try and use `Thread.sleep`. I would be glad if you could put more effort into understanding in what context we are before writing such nonsense as `You should never use  ...`.

Comment: I put efforts into understanding of context. Still, you should not advise `Thread.sleep` for any kind of determinism, especially to beginners. Proper wording would be "spawned threads are not immediately ready... to confirm that you can put Thread.sleep in the main loop"

Comment: I ended up using the Thread.sleep method and it worked for my code, each day having a random amount of buyers and sellers. I'm not sure why this would be bad practice?

Comment: @whywontitrun "I'm not sure why this would be bad practice? " answer is rather big so I added post instead of comment

Answer (score 0):

If I understand task correctly, then buyers and sellers should make some deals before the day ends and then new day should start (not earlier).

If so then using `Thread.sleep` is bad solution here for two reasons

1. If you set short delay then new day may start when deals are not done yet
2. If you set long delay (and in real prod environment it is quite a task to determine what is long enough to cover all possible future scenarios) then in most cases you will waste thread (*) + your code could be visible slow

Proper solution will be not guessing if deals are done or not but waiting for the event "all deals are done".

It could be achieved in a multiple ways (CountDownLatch, atomic counter etc) but easiest is to wait when all threads started for a day are stopped

```
while (day <= 30){
       System.out.println("Day " + day + " beginning. There are " + carShowroom.getCars().size()  + " cars in the showroom today.");

        int randomSeller = rand.nextInt(3);
        int randomBuyer = rand.nextInt(3);

        List<Thread> allThreads = new List<>(randomSeller+randomBuyer+2);

        for (int j = 0; j <= randomSeller; j++){
            Seller seller = new Seller(carShowroom);
            Thread mySellerThread = new Thread(seller);
            mySellerThread.start();
            allThreads.add(mySellerThread);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= randomBuyer; i++){
            Buyer buyer = new Buyer(carShowroom);
            Thread myBuyerThread = new Thread(buyer);
            myBuyerThread.start();
            allThreads.add(myBuyerThread);
        }

        for (Thread t : allThreads) {
          t.join();
        }

        // "all deals are done"

        day++;
    }
```

`t.join` causes main thread (which loops the days) to wait until thread is done (== `seller.run()` or `buyer.run()` methods are completed). If thread is already finished then `t.join` is also safe, it will just exit.

Once you verified all sellers and buyers threads are done, you know "all deals are done"

(*) For example, if your days loop is executed in the thread taken from the pool then while you are doing `sleep` thread does not do any job and cannot be used for any other task as well.